# How to access a table in a wordpress database using REST API?

Tags: database, rest-api

I have a wordpress database. There are some tables in it.

[image]

I want to access the table contents of the table `wp_fa_user_logins` **using REST API** to know when a user logged in. I know I can SSH into the database or connect to it using and SQL client, but that's not what I need.

Comment: There's no shortcut, you need to create your own API that queries the data and formats it for response: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/ But if you're trying to implement some sort of remote authentication, then this doesn't seem like the right way to do it. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm not planning for remote authentication. Here's the problem I'm working on: I need to generate a report/graph about user activity on the website. Number of times a user logged in the last month and so on. I installed a plugin in wordpress which stores this info in a table. The job will be run in an AWS lambda written in Python. So it has to regularly fetch user activity info using an API, generate the report. Repeat.